# Multi-Column Repeating Values with new dates

Tags: google-sheets

So I am making a sheet with three columns that I want repeating except for every new three columns I want to have a different date (previous date+1). I am unsure as how to go about this, I have seen some stuff about dataframes and matrices, but do not know if that's overkill or something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Warren, can you edit your question to share with us a sample sheet with the expected results ?